# Remounting a Device with a Different Filesystem without reboot

Tags: filesystems

I do have a device mounted as `ext4` but actually it is `ext3`, is there a way that I can make it mount simply again as `ext3` without rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

Unnecessary, don't bother remounting.

Linux 2.6.29 or later (which almost certainly you have) can [mount ext2 or ext3 as ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_mount_existing_Ext3_as_Ext4.3F_And_vice_versa.3F_Similarly_from_Ext2_to_Ext4_and_its_reverse.3F).

(ext4 features will be absent, adding them requires e2fsck, implying downtime to umount.)